# Scraping With Scrapy tool

Tags: python

I am a beginner with the scrapy tool and my project consists in recovering the description of
products on alibaba, as well as the pictures

thank in advance

I tried to retrieve the description as well as the image of the associated products of all the articles of the products from the link,
but

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome here. Please note that stackoverflow is meant to help you with specific coding problems, where you post your example code and ask for help. It's not meant for general questions.

It would be best to deactivate this question and come back later, if you have a specific problem to avoid getting downvoted.

Comment: Explain your question properly, posting half question without code won't help you much.